# Sort one array and have corresponding values in second array swap C++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int years = 0;
  int startingYear = 0;

  cout << "Enter the number of years: ";
  cin >> years;
  cout << "Enter the starting year: ";
  cin >> startingYear; 

  int statArray[years];
  int yearArray[years];
  int length = sizeof(statArray)/sizeof(int);

  for (int i = 0; i <length; i++) {
    cout << "Enter the stat for the year " << startingYear << ": ";
    cin >> statArray[i];
    yearArray[i] = startingYear;
    startingYear++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < length-1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < length-i-1; j++) {
      if (statArray[j] > statArray[j+1]) {
        int temp = statArray[j];
        int tempYear = yearArray[j];
        statArray[j] = statArray[j+1];
        yearArray[j] = yearArray[j+1];
        statArray[j+1] = temp;
        yearArray[j] = tempYear;
      }
    }
  }
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      cout <<yearArray[i] << "|";
      }
}
```

The first array sorts just fine, values in second array do not get swapped.

Array one takes sports scores and the second array is a list of years for those scores. I am sorting the first array to be in ascending order. I need the second array as the output.

Comment: Whichever C++ textbook offered "`int statArray[years];`" as an example must be thrown away and replaced by a better C++ textbook, because this is non-standard C++.

Comment: What's a better way to declare one?

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for the swap does not match.  Notice the "working" one assigns to index `j+1` and the "non-working" one doesn't.

```
statArray[j+1] = temp;
yearArray[j] = tempYear;
```

So, the fix should be this:

```
statArray[j+1] = temp;
yearArray[j+1] = tempYear;
```

It is far preferable to use `std::swap` to swap values.  If there is some crazy reason why you can't use that function, then write a swap function yourself instead of doing it inline like this.  That reduces code clutter and reduces the chance for mistakes:

```
std::swap(statArray[j], statArray[j+1]);
std::swap(yearArray[j], yearArray[j+1]);
```

Note also this whole operation can be done with `std::sort` instead, which is far, far superior to your own algorithm.  It can be setup such that it sorts an array of indices, which can then be used to order any number of arrays.

[Edit] I would like to thank the OP for deleting their question after I took the time to provide an answer.  Thanks for recognizing the efforts of this community to offer free help.

Comment: Hey man, I didn't mean to just delete the post after you had answered it. I deleted the post as I had realized my issue. At the time of deleting the post I did not see that anyone had responded. I figured it had not been seen by anyone.

With that being said, I do want to thank you for your reply. It is greatly appreciated. As for the swap function, thank you for that, I'm new to c++ and did not know such a thing existed. I wrote the program the way I did as that's the way I have been taught in the course I am taking. 

Anyways, I apologize for upsetting you, I truly appreciate your help.